# How can I trigger codebuild via webhook for pull request declined event from bitbucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, aws-codebuild

I am using Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org)  as source control and codebuild as CI tool. I am able to trigger codebuild job from bitbucket via webhook but I can't find a way to trigger it if a PR is declined. When reading this article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-codebuild-project-webhookfilter.html, `PULL_REQUEST_DECLINED` event is not listed.

Below is my filter for webhook:

```
Triggers:
              Webhook: true
              FilterGroups:
                - - Pattern: PUSH,PULL_REQUEST_CREATED,PULL_REQUEST_UPDATED,PULL_REQUEST_MERGED
                  Type: EVENT
```

If I add `PULL_REQUEST_DECLINED` there, cloudformation will return an error about unsupported filter event.

So how can I trigger it for PR declined event?

The reason I need to add declined event is that my codebuild deploys some resources to AWS when a PR is created, then there will be some integration tests are running. I'd like to remove all these resources when the PR is merged or declined.

Answer (score 0):

First - just to make sure we're being clear, are you using Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org) or Bitbucket Server?

From the documentation you linked, it looks like simply specifying a new expected EVENT pattern matching the payload you're getting from Bitbucket should be what you need.

In either case, I recommend looking over the full payload documentation for Bitbucket webhooks (assuming you're not using a third-party app or something) and use an attribute specific to that type of payload in creating the filter/listener in codebuild:

- [Bitbucket Cloud Event Payloads](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/event-payloads/)
- [Bitbucket Server Event Payloads](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/event-payload-938025882.html)

  - ⚠️ Be sure to adjust top right dropdown to match your version number

Comment: Following up on my previous comment - it looks like some of the other [Bitbucket-specific codebuild documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/bitbucket-webhook.html) clearly showcases that triggering builds off of a PR being declined isn't accounted for, and is likely an unanticipated use case. Although it may be possible to do something super strange like try and rewrite the event key mid-flight through a proxy, but I think the better solution would be to step back and understand why you're building on declines.

Comment: I am using bitbucket cloud and I have put the use case in the question. The codebuild doesn't support parsing the payload.